# Is $(1+2+3+…)=(1+2+2^2+2^3+…)(1+3+3^2+…)(1+5+5^2+…)…$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Are these equal?
$$(1+2+3+…)=(1+2+2^2+…)(1+3+3^2+…)(1+5+5^2+…)…$$
Where the RHS has a series for each prime. Looks like they are the same series by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Every number on the LHS is a product of prime factors which can be obtained from the right hand side by choosing the appropriate numbers from each contributing prime and $1$ from the rest and conversely.

By a similar argument, it looks like:

$$(1+2+3+\dots)=(1+2+3+5+\dots)(1+2+3+5+\dots)(1+2+3+5+\dots)\dots$$

Comment: Your second "similar argument" isn't right. There are more than one (infinite) ways to, say, make $2$.

Comment: Well, they (the first ones) are "the same" in the sense that each and every summand in the LHS appears exactly once in the RHS, and the other way around...and they're also "the same" in the sense both expressions are *not* converging to anything finite...

Comment: These are a little divergent.

Comment: For the second one, you might try to see that $\infty = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try proving
$$
(1^s+2^s+3^s+\dots)=(1^s+2^s+2^{2s}+\dots)(1^s+3^s+3^{2s}+\dots)(1^s+5^s+5^{2s}+\dots)\dots
$$
for $s$ such that the series converge.

The left side is $\zeta(-s)$, the factors on the right side are geometric series.  I think your result will be a well-known formula.  But there are analytic continuations for all of these to other values of $s$ where the series diverge.  Put $s=1$ to get a conclusion, $\zeta(-1) = \dots$.